# Why does the website 404 when I add a "/" at the end of the url (Flask)?

Tags: python, flask, routes

When I go to my (imaginary website), it works:

> mywebsite.com/flowers

But if I add a "/" at the end, I get a "Not Found" error:

> mywebsite.com/flowers/

Assuming my route is:

```
@app.route('/flowers', methods=['GET'])
def xyz():..
```

Am I supposed to redirect "/flowers/" to /"flowers" or am I supposed to add multiple routes? I'm not sure how it's supposed to work without copy-pasting my entire function for every (original route + "/").

Comment: try to route to `/flowers/`

Comment: Ok that leads automatically to the correct path, but why is that and not the opposite? Is this something I should know about Flask?

Comment: just a small mishab in flasks routing system im guessing, no clue honestly. You could ask on the flasks github: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flask, the URL redirection with and without trailing `/` works differently.

```
@app.route('/works/')
def works():
    return 'This works'

@app.route('/sorry')
def sorry():
    return 'sorry'
```

The URL for the `works` endpoint has a trailing slash. It’s similar to a folder in a file system. If you access the URL without a trailing slash (`/works`), Flask redirects you to the URL with the trailing slash `/works/`.

The URL for the `sorry` endpoint does not have a trailing slash. It’s similar to the pathname of a file. Accessing the URL with a trailing slash `/sorry/` produces a **404 "Not Found"** error.

Alternatively,  to make this works at the application level, You can use

```
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

Setting `strict_slashes` to False will work as expected with the `/sorry/` route.

URL routes that end with a slash are **branches**, others are **leaves**. If `strict_slashes` is enabled (the default), visiting a branch URL without a trailing slash will redirect to the URL with a slash appended.

Reference: [Flask doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior) , [Werkzeug Docs](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/routing/#rule-format)